# Digikey part price python script

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to write a script to search digikey.com for a part and return the price breaks for each. I am having trouble however opening the url. I have looked at other similar scripts and this is what I have come up with but I get errors with BeautifulSoup. I am using Python 2.7 and running Ubuntu 13.04.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This script will find the page of a part and return the price 
# break information

import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


# Create Url to read
Digikey_url = 'http://digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name='
partNum = '458-1003-ND'
url=Digikey_url+partNum

# Create BeautifulSoup Object 
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)


# Close Page
page.close()
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DigiKeyPrice.py", line 17, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Also I am kind of new to python but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

with:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Plus, `response` variable is not defined, replace:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: ahhh... I see I forgot to change that variable, I was trying to go off of some other examples. But I thought that if I just did `import BeautifulSoup` it would import the whole module. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Yup, but you need `BeautifulSoup` class from `BeautifulSoup` module.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what my problem was. I thought I had read that I can just import everything from BeautifulSoup but I see now where my issue was and that makes sense why I was getting the error I was getting.